# Continued MVC Area 404 error. At wit's end

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[EDITED] Code and solution edited as per suggestions from forum members.  I've corrected the name of the controller. It was incorrect.  The corrected name is shown in the updated solution file snapshot.  I'm getting a new error.  The new error is shown in the updated snapshot.  It's still a 404-typpe error.

As for the "post your routing edits" type of comments, please note the original statement that Visual Studio has done all the wireup for me.  It's my understanding that if I'm right-clicking and adding controllers, views, etc. from the IDE that I do not need to go in and do additional wireup behind the scenes.  This seems to defeat the whole purpose of an easy-to-implement interface.  Please correct me if I misunderstand.  Thanks.[END EDIT]

I asked for help with this problem earlier and nobody was able to solve.  I've retooled the solution, deleting everything involved and starting over, in hopes it would relieve the problem.  I'm still stuck.  This is a very simple thing according to all I've read on MVC but I have been dead in the water for over a week.  Would appreciate help on this.  My retooled code appears below.  I've looked at similar errors reported in these forums and found no help.

Please note that all the wireup was done completely by Visual Studio: I have not modified any generated code behind the scenes other than adding an Action method to the controller.  In other words, everything was generated by right-clicking in VS and selecting "Add" and following the prompts for views, controllers, etc.

I have a view in one area, "UserAccount", that uses Html.ActionLink() to generate a link to a view in another area, "DocumentUploaderNew".  A screen snapshot of the markup is below.  When I click the rendered button in IE though, I get an error that seems like a "404" error.  The view IS there though.

This has GOT to be an embarrassingly easy answer.  I'm ready to eat humble pie.  What is it???

[image: The updated solution]
[image: The Html.ActionLink() call]
[image: The new controller code]
[image: The new error]

Comment: Here's the `ActionLink` [overload list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: You also need to post your route for the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is failing is because your view `FileUploaderNew.cshtml` is at the root of the Views folder and not in a folder itself (either one with the name of the controller or the shared view folder).  If you look at the paths that MVC is checking in your error screenshot, you can see it never checks the path `~/Areas/DocumentUploaderNew/Views/FileUploaderNew.cshtml`

There are numerous fixes you can do to fix this problem (choose one, not all three).

1. Create a folder in your Views folder called `FileUploaderNew` and move your `FileUploaderNew.cshtml` file into that folder (basically, you create a subfolder in the views folder with the name of a matching controller.  The view engine will look for that folder when returning Views from that controller).
2. Move the `FileUploaderNew.cshtml` file into the Shared folder inside the Views folder (you can see it in your screenshot).
3. Specify exactly where your view is when you call `Return View()`:

```
return View("~/Areas/DocumentUploaderNew/Views/FileUploaderNew.cshtml");
```

Comment: I think based on the "regular" structure of MVC projects your first  suggestion would be the best one to fix this issue. Basically, MVC is going to be looking for a folder in the views folder named whatever the controller is named by default. Pretty much what I would have posted as an answer. +1

Comment: @DROPTABLEusers - I approved your edit, but the reason I didn't use markdown on the list is because you cannot format code afterwards.  If you can tell me how to do that, that would be awesome (look at my last line)

Comment: Moving the view or specifying the location explicitly does indeed ultimately solve the problem.  THANK YOU.  It was that extra nesting inside a subfolder that I was missing.  I did also, in my original post, have an incorrectly named ActionResult method in my controller, but it would have STILL failed because of view not being in the /FileUploaderNew subfolder (or the Shared subfolder).

Comment: @markaaronky - Yup, going forward just remember that the way the View engine tries and finds the view is by looking for a subfolder with the name of the controller in the Views folder.  If you using the view for multiple controllers, place it in your Shared folder.  Else, the conventions dictate that you should create that controller named view subfolder.  Glad we could get your project working again!  As a side note, I addressed one of your other 404 error questions that you posted previously (same type of issue).

Comment: @Tommy yeah, strange. I ended up just putting an empty tag to resolve the formatting issue. Found the resolution helpfully [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34292/code-blocks-after-a-list-but-not-within-a-list-in-markdown-is-it-possible).

Answer (score 6):

That's because your controller is actually named `FileUpload`, yet you're trying to use the controller name `FileUploaderNew` (looks like you're getting confused with your action and controller names).

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Upload New", "FileUploaderNew", new { controller = "FileUpload", area = "DocumentUploaderNew" }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I did indeed have a typo on the controller name.  I have corrected that and am getting a new error.  It seems the view still cannot be found.  I have edited my original post (WHICH I HOPE IS THE CORRECT CONVENTION IN THIS FORUM) with the updated code and the new error message.  Again, the help is greatly appreciated and I hope the noob questions are not too frustrating to deal with.

Comment: This did indeed lead me down the path to a solution, as the method was incorrectly named, but the showstopper (even after renaming) was that the way the Html.ActionLink() call is written, the view either had to be in a *SUBFOLDER* named \FileUploaderNew, or in the Shared subfolder, or the path had to be spelled out.  Just wanted to add this comment (with a word of thanks) and point to the answer below that ultimately pulled it all together.

Comment: @markaaronky No problems, glad you eventually got there :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your route is, it'll either be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Upload New", "FileUploaderNew", new { controller = "FileUpload/FileUploaderNew"}, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

or

```
@Html.ActionLink("Upload New", "FileUploaderNew", new { controller = "DocumentUploader/Controllers/FileUpload/FileUploaderNew"}, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

The jist is you have to post to the controller's path (not name) and when you don't it can't find it & you get a 404.  In a default MVC file structure, I believe this is automated (controllers in the controllers directory auto map without paths), but that's not your file structure.

Also, I'm answering this never having used areas, not sure if those factor into the equation, but a quick read seems to indicate they're more for locking down paths than finding them.